# HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla - в Safari, и Chrome

Tags: php

Вывожу в пхп

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Выводит вот что для Сафари

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
```

Вот что для хрома

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
```

Вопрос: 
**Почему везде пишет в начале Mozilla/5.0?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вся [история `User-Agent`'ов](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) это печальная история несоблюдения стандартов, вендорных расширений, расползания их поддержки по разным браузерам и попыток выявления поддерживаемых клиентами расширений/технологий.

Браузеры наперебой заявляли о поддержке возомжностей друг друга, чтобы сайты, которые по определённым паттернам `User-Agent`'ов отдают *полную* или *совместимую* версии "не ущемляли" нововышедший браузер, который якобы поддерживает нужные новинки, но сообщать об этом вынужден с помощью "чужих" элементов в своём `User-Agent`, поскольку именно на него тогда смотрели сайты.

Кроме `Mozilla/5.0` порой неожиданно встречаются ещё и `KHTML`, `like Gecko` (Gecko это движок Firefox) и `Safari`.

В общем, это **тяжкое историческое наследие**, которое сейчас [ехидно высмеивается](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yf8ACKrZTJI#t=9m05s) (*Bruce Lawson, Opera Software, "Как уничтожить Веб", слайд "A short sad story of browser sniffing"*).
По словам Брюса, префикс `Mozilla` браузеры повально добавляли, чтобы заявить о поддержке **фреймов**.

Comment: Печальная действительность. Правда теперь это рудимент - всем, кому надо определять, знают это и внимания не обращают.

Answer (score 0):

> Использование веб-сайтами строки User-agent для изменения отображения
>   страницы часто приводит к тому, что менее популярные браузеры не
>   получают полного содержимого страницы, даже если они могут корректно
>   его отобразить, а в некоторых радикальных случаях такие браузеры не
>   получают вообще ничего. В связи с этим многие браузеры стали «прятать»
>   или «подделывать» User-agent.
>
> Ранний пример этого — использование браузером Internet Explorer строки
>   User-Agent, начинающейся с «Mozilla/ (compatible; MSIE
>   …», для получения контента, предназначенного для Netscape
>   Navigator, его главного конкурента в 1990-х. Нужно отметить, что
>   «Mozilla» в данном случае — не браузер с открытым кодом Mozilla,
>   выпущенный гораздо позже, а оригинальное кодовое имя Navigator,
>   которое также было именем талисмана (маскота) компании Netscape. Такой
>   формат строки User-Agent с тех пор использовался и другими браузерами;
>   в частности, из-за того, что доминировать стал Internet Explorer.
>
> Когда Internet Explorer стал доминирующим браузером, такие конкуренты
>   как Firefox, Safari и Opera встроили системы, позволяющие пользователю
>   выбрать ложное значение User-Agent, такое же, что и у свежих версий
>   Explorer. Некоторые из них (Firefox и Safari) копировали значение
>   User-Agent полностью, другие (Opera) копировали значение User-Agent,
>   добавляя истинное имя браузера в конце, что позже привело к тому, что
>   строка содержит три имени и версии: первое зовётся как «Mozilla» (то
>   есть Netscape Navigator); далее «MSIE» (Internet Explorer); и
>   последнее, действительный браузер, такой как «Opera». Opera также
>   позволяла полностью замаскироваться под Internet Explorer или Firefox,
>   полностью скрывая имя «Opera».

Взято [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent#.D0.98.D1.81.D0.BA.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C)

Comment: `Mozilla` - `Mosaic killer`.